# Toggle Individual Functions When an Event is Clicked - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, events, click

I'd like to call a function that toggles on a node list of elements with the same class.  I basically need to add the function within the if else statement, but the different variants of this seem to throw an error.  When I put the code that is inside the two functions directly into the if else statement it works, but I want to do it with functions because this is a simplified version of what will be more complex style changes.

Codepen is here:https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/GEEpqW?editors=1111

Code is below:

JS

```
var $mainMenuButton = document.getElementsByClassName('desktopmenubutton');

function newColor() {
  e.currentTarget.style.background = "black";
}

function originalColor() {
  e.currentTarget.style.background = "red";
}

for (h = 0; h < $mainMenuButton.length; h +=1) {
  $mainMenuButton[h].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor === "red") {
      newColor();
    } else {
      originalColor();
    }
  });
}
```

CSS

```
* {font-family: arial;}

.desktopmenubutton {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white
}

.button2 {
  left: 300px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="desktopmenubutton button1">Button 1</div>
<div class="desktopmenubutton button2">Button 2</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the element in the function that is inside the `if` statement.

```
 var $mainMenuButton = document.getElementsByClassName('desktopmenubutton button1');

    function newColor(element) {
      element.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }

    function originalColor(element) {
      element.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

    for (h = 0; h < $mainMenuButton.length; h +=1) {
      $mainMenuButton[h].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor === "red") {
          newColor(e);
        } else {
          originalColor(e);
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to receive the event as a parameter on `newColor` and `originalColor`.

```
var $mainMenuButton = 
document.getElementsByClassName('desktopmenubutton');

function newColor(e) {
  e.currentTarget.style.background = "black";
}

function originalColor(e) {
  e.currentTarget.style.background = "red";
}

for (h = 0; h < $mainMenuButton.length; h +=1) {
  $mainMenuButton[h].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor === "red") {
      newColor(e);
    } else {
      originalColor(e);
    }
  });
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `e`(event) argument

Also note that `Element.style.*` reads inline css styles, not those styles which are assigned in `CSS` file/tag.

You could set `red` color initially in `loop` so that it could be accessed using `Element.style.*` property.

```js
var $mainMenuButton = document.getElementsByClassName('desktopmenubutton');

function newColor(e) {
  e.currentTarget.style.background = "black";
}

function originalColor(e) {
  e.currentTarget.style.background = "red";
}

for (h = 0; h < $mainMenuButton.length; h += 1) {
  $mainMenuButton[h].style.background = 'red';
  $mainMenuButton[h].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.style.background == 'red') {
      newColor(e);
    } else {
      originalColor(e);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
}

.desktopmenubutton {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white
}

.button2 {
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="desktopmenubutton button1">Button 1</div>
<div class="desktopmenubutton button2">Button 2</div>
```